# Forward all requests but handle root call differently

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain (e.g. `doma.in`) I am only using for forwarding purposes. So I created this `.htaccess` definition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This successfully forwards calls in the following scheme

```
http://doma.in/abc     -> http://www.mydomain.tld/in/abc
http://doma.in/123     -> http://www.mydomain.tld/in/123
http://doma.in/abc/123 -> http://www.mydomain.tld/in/abc/123
```

But I want to forward the root call, with or without `www`:

```
http://doma.in
http://www.doma.in
http://doma.in/
http://www.doma.in/
```

to the root URL of `http://www.mydomain.tld`.

I have tried to add another `RewriteCond`, but this setting throws a server error on all calls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/o/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond ^(.*)doma.in/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld [R=301,L]
```

How do I have to adapt my `.htaccess` in order to support my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# root URL
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.mydomain.tld/ [R=301,L]

# all but root URL
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test this in a a new browser to avoid old 301 cache.